# ImageSlider memory leak c#

Tags: c#

I used a code like this in a program that I have created but I have slight problem of ram memory to which it keeps increase and it is hoging all the of the ram.  So every time it changes images the memory increases.  What I want to do is dispose of the previous image so I do not bottle neck the memory.  Or if there is a better way to create a slide show with a timer that does not bottle neck the memory just point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

```
private string [] folderFile = null;
private int selected = 0;
private int begin = 0; 
private int end = 0;


private void showImage(string path)
 {
   Image imgtemp = Image.FromFile(path);
   pictureBox1.Image = imgtemp;
 }

private void nextImage()
{
  if(selected == folderFile.Length - 1)
{
  selected = 0;
  showImage(folderFile[selected]);
}
else
{
 selected = selected + 1; 
 showImage(folderFile[selected]);
}
}

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   nextImage();
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to dispose of the previous images.

```
private void showImage(string path)
{
   Image oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;
   Image imgtemp = Image.FromFile(path);
   pictureBox1.Image = imgtemp;
   if(oldImage != null)
       oldImage.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling `Image.Dispose` on the previous value of `pictureBox1.Image`.

You want to make the following changes.

```
private void showImage(string path)
{
   Image imgtemp = Image.FromFile(path);
   Image oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;
   pictureBox1.Image = imgtemp;
   if (oldImage != null) oldImage.Dispose();
}
```

`Image` is an unmanaged object, which is a wrapper for the GDI classes.